# Improve the time complexity of my implementation of Counting Sort (C)

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, counting-sort

Consider the following code:

```
#define SIZE 12

void randomize(int* array, int array_size);
void print(int* array, int array_size);
void counting_sort(int* array, int array_size);
int get_max(int* array, int array_size);
void construct(int* sorted, int sorted_array_size, int* values);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int* array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    randomize(array, SIZE);
    print(array, SIZE);
    counting_sort(array, SIZE);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}

void randomize(int* array, int array_size) {...}

void print(int* array, int array_size) {...}

void counting_sort(int* array, int array_size) {
    int minVal, maxVal;
    int* sorted = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    maxVal = get_max(array, array_size);

    int* values = (int*)malloc(maxVal * sizeof(int));

    memset(values, 0, maxVal * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        values[array[i]]++;
    }

    construct(sorted, SIZE, values);

    free(values);
    free(sorted);
    }

int get_max(int* array, int array_size) {...}

void construct(int* sorted, int array_size, int* values) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        while (!values[++j]);
        sorted[i] = j;
        --values[j];
    }
    print(sorted, SIZE);
}
```

`main()` declares an array, the size of which is controlled by the macro `SIZE`. Then there are a few functions to randomize, print and find the max value of that array. After that is the implementation of Counting Sort itself, which uses the `construct(..)` function to create the sorted array. I've tested it a few times and couldn't find any bugs. However this bit right here is what I'm concerned about.

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
            while (!values[++j]);...
```

We have 2 inner loops, and the variables in these loops are incremented. This means that the time complexity of the `construct(...)` function becomes quadratic, and not linear. The issue is that I can't figure out a good way to discard all of the `0` in `values[]`. Linear solutions are most welcome.

Added full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 160

void randomize(int* array, int array_size);
void print(int* array, int array_size);
void counting_sort(int* array, int array_size);
int get_max(int* array, int array_size);
void construct(int* sorted, int sorted_array_size, int* values);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int* array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    randomize(array, SIZE);
    print(array, SIZE);
    counting_sort(array, SIZE);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}

void randomize(int* array, int array_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % array_size;
    }
}

void print(int* array, int array_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        printf("%4d ", array[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void counting_sort(int* array, int array_size) {
    int minVal, maxVal;
    int* sorted = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    maxVal = get_max(array, array_size);

    int* values = (int*)malloc(maxVal * sizeof(int));

    memset(values, 0, maxVal * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        values[array[i]]++;
    }

    construct(sorted, SIZE, values);

    free(values);
    free(sorted);
}

int get_max(int* array, int array_size) {
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        if (max < array[i]) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void construct(int* sorted, int array_size, int* values) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        while (!values[j]) {
            ++j;
        }
        sorted[i] = j;
        --values[j];
    }
    print(sorted, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Does that code even work? Have you tried it with an array like `{5,5,5,0,0,0}`?

Comment: Yes, it works with an array like that, @user3386109

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). The obvious performance loss in this program is the lack of 2D arrays - instead you are working with segments scattered all over the heap. Also, calloc might potentially be ever so slightly faster than malloc + memset.

Comment: "_becomes quadratic, and not linear._" no because you never reset _j_ nor decrements it, so the complexity is 2*array_size (values have the same size as sorted if I well understand) ... supposing your algo is correct (like @user3386109 I a not sure of that, but you do not give all the code)

Comment: First of all you have UB by accessing out of bound, suppose you have an array `{0,5,4}` maximum element being `5` then you allocate `values` with size `5` and you access `values[5]` in the loop (`values[array[i]]++;`).

Comment: The full code has no resemblance to the original code. You should delete the original, and fix the snippet you're asking about to match the full code.

Comment: Also consider the bug which @KiranBiradar has pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is linear. You have an inner while loop, but the value of `j` is never reset to `0`, it keeps growing in each iteration of the for loop. Overall `i` will count from `0` to `size` and `j` will count from `0` to `n`.